# Update if(condition) or produce an error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need do an update a table via php.
    I need the response will be Ok or Error.
    Basically, i need substract 1 to the field value, if field value is not zero.
    If the field value is zero, i try to force produce an error, replacing the numeric field with a string value

The SQL statement is:

```
$query = "Update mytable set myfield = if( myfield > 0 , myfield - 1 , 'AAA') where cliente_id = $cual_ID";
```

After this, the php code is:

```
if (mysql_query($query))
    {
        echo "OK";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error 4";
    }

mysql_close($link);
```

When I run the php, it always return OK, also when myfield is greater than zero.

Any ideas?

Comment: `mysql_query` only returns false if the query fails to execute.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of producing an error a possible solution is to introduce an additional condition to `WHERE` clause `myfield > 0` of your update statement and use [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) to see if a row was updated

```
$query = "UPDATE mytable 
             SET myfield = myfield - 1
           WHERE cliente_id = $cual_ID
             AND myfield > 0";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "Error 4";
}
mysql_close($link);
```

**On a side note:** instead of interpolating query strings consider to use **[prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** with either [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are validating the boolean return, in full you are doing :

```
if (mysql_query($Query) === true){
 // Mysql is returning true
  echo "OK";
}else{
 //MySQL is returning false
}
```

You need to perform other tasks with your query.. eg:

```
$Query = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($Query) > 0){
 // Rows detected are greater than 0
 echo "OK";
}else{
 // Rows detected are less than 0
 echo "Error";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your SQL query to this:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET myfield = CASE
    WHEN myfield = 0 THEN 'AAA'
    WHEN myfield > 0 THEN myfield - 1
    ELSE myfield = myfield 
    END
WHERE cliente_id = $cual_ID
```

Also you should reconsider the *forcing an error* way to do this. I think there are better approaches (for example, determining if any row has been changed or not).